# Чтение и редактирование Word-документа

Tags: java, ms-word

Необходимо прочитать и отредактировать некоторый шаблон Word документа на основе пользовательского ввода. Реально ли это сделать, учитывая, что документ 180+ страниц, содержит много картинок, таблиц и т.д.?

Уже видел и просмотрел много различных библиотек, но все говорят, что у каждой из них есть серьёзные недостатки. Если кто-то работал, подскажите пожалуйста, чтобы на грабли не наступать.

Comment: может лучше будет C# или даже VBA ?

Comment: я полностью согласен, что так будет лучше, но нужна именно java

Comment: Apach POI с Exel работает, может поддержка Word тоже есть !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). При работе проблем с производительностью не замечал. Есть поддержка документов Microsoft Word как старых форматов, так и новых:

- `HWPF` (для .doc файлов) - [с чего начать](https://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide.html) (документации и примеров не особо много, но найти можно).
- `XWPF` (для .docx файлов) - [с чего начать](https://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html), [примеры использования](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/), [Apache POI Word - Overview](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm).

Comment: Не подскажите, он способен работать с таблицами, изображениями, цветами, заливкой и тд?

Comment: Если вы посмотрите приведенные ссылки, то увидите примеры работы с таблицей, изображениями и стилями текста. Но тут многое зависит от формата документа. Если это .doc, то он поддерживается в меньшей степени.